# Where and when add element with data-bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datatables

My problem is , I don't where to add `$(ele).html('some html')` to my script because it's either to early or to late to add it. Here is my actual problem:

### First I create viemModel

```
var mainAdmin = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.pageLanguage = mainAdminDTLanguage;
    self.tableData = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.dataTable = ko.observable(null);
    /*self.tableRowClick = function(data) {
        var checkCode = confirm('Vai atzīmēt šo kuponu?');
        if(checkCode){
            alert(data[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/code/mark/'+data[0],
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    };*/
    self.tableOptions = { aaSorting: [["1","desc"]] };
    self.dtSelectValue = ko.observable('visus');
    self.initLoad = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/all',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index) {
                    self.tableData.push([this.ID,this.Title, Dateformat('M jS, H:i:s',new Date(this.EndDate)),'<button>Dzēst</button>']);
                    console.log(this.ID);
                });
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    };
    self.recentItemLoad = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/inactive',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                self.tableData([]);
                $.each(data, function(index) {
                    self.tableData.push([this.ID,this.Title, Dateformat('M jS, H:i:s',new Date(this.EndDate)),'<button>Dzēst</button>']);
                    console.log(this.ID);
                });
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    };
    self.activeItemLoad = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/active',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                self.tableData([]);
                $.each(data, function(index) {
                    self.tableData.push([this.ID,this.Title, Dateformat('M jS, H:i:s',new Date(this.EndDate)),'<button>Dzēst</button>']);
                    console.log(this.ID);
                });
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    self.dtSelectValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   (newValue == 'visus') ? mainViewModel.mainAdminPage.initLoad() : (newValue == 'aktīvos') ? mainViewModel.mainAdminPage.activeItemLoad() : (newValue == 'neaktīvos') ? mainViewModel.mainAdminPage.recentItemLoad() : false
});
};
```

**Yes I know it's bit messy but really I didn't have time to optimize it yet**

### Then I create jQuery's DataTable binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor();
    var defaults = {
        "aaData": options["data"](),
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "oLanguage": options["language"],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sDom": '<"H"l<"dt-toolbar">fr>t<"F"ip>',
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            $(nRow).mouseover(function(){
              $(nRow).attr("style","background-color:yellow !important;");
            });  
            $(nRow).mouseout(function() {
              $(nRow).removeAttr("style");
            });
            if(typeof options["rowClick"] === "function") {
              $(nRow).click(function() {
                options["rowClick"](aData);
              });  
            }  
            return nRow;
        },    
    };
    var tableOptions = $.extend(defaults,options["options"]);
    options["object"]($(element).dataTable(tableOptions));
    $("div.dt-toolbar")
        .html('Rādīt <select data-bind="value: $data.dtSelectValue"><option>visus</option><option>aktīvos</option><option>neaktīvos</option></select> kuponus');
  },
  update: function(element,valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor();
    options["object"]().fnClearTable();
    options["object"]().fnAddData(options["data"](),true);
  }
};
```

**You can see I create the** `$("div.dt-toolbar")
            .html('Rādīt <select data-bind="value: $data.dtSelectValue"><option>visus</option><option>aktīvos</option><option>neaktīvos</option></select> kuponus');` @ `init`!

### Then I create mainViewModel and apply bindings

```
// --- mainView viewmodel
var mainViewModel = {
    indexPage: new indexViewModel(),
    itemPage: new itemViewModel(),
    catPage: new categoryViewModel(),
    companyPage: new companyAdmin(),
    mainAdminPage: new mainAdmin()
};

// --Applied bindings
ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel);
```

**Now** you can see that I'm creating DataTable after apply bindings, basically at this order:

1. viewModel
2. mainViewModel
3. custom bindings
4. create HTML
5. applyBindings to html
6. create html with `data-bind`

### Question

1. How can I apply binding to that exact element without going inot infinte loop?

Answer (score 0):

So basically I figured out that I could make function, that will update `$("div.dt-toolbar")` dynamically with `html` by creating new function inside `mainAdmin`

```
self.updateDTmenu = function () {
        $("div.dt-toolbar")
        .html('Rādīt <select data-bind="value: dtSelectValue"><option value="visus">visus</option><option value="aktīvos">aktīvos</option><option value="neaktīvos">neaktīvos</option></select> kuponus');
        ko.applyBindings(new mainAdmin(), $("div.dt-toolbar")[0]);
    };
```

and then inside `dataTable` binding instead of `$("div.dt-toolbar").html('someHtml');` write this `mainViewModel.mainAdminPage.updateDTmenu();`

And this way it applies only itself to the element and can create any element dynamically!

Answer (score 0):

why not use `foreach` to do binding for table? you pull certain "html elements" into your view model, which is a bad practice I think.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: tableData, afterRender: a function }>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 ...
</tr>
```

to select, you could use binding for options,

```
<select data-bind="options: optionsData">
</select>
```

here is a link to [knockoutjs foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)